# Page title unable to overwrite default title

Tags: 7, meta-tags

`admin/config/search/page-title` - Global default title is *abc*

`admin/config/search/page-title` - Content type *BOOK* -> title is *def*

meta tag -> Content -> page title is *ghi*

meta tag -> Content -> BOOK -> page title is *jkl*

content type *BOOK* -> create new node -> page title -> *mno*

In the website(Content type Book), the title always shows *abc*.

I want to edit title, may I know how?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (!empty($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id']) && $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id'] == 'form_id') {
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'node-type') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Your title'));
    }
   }
 }
```

you can use dpm($variables) to find form id. This for changing page title.

For changing header title i.e the title displaying in tab, below code can be used

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id']) && $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['#form_id'] == 'your_form_id') {
    $vars['head_title'] = t('title');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit)

Using this module you can edit your title field.

OR

you can do it by custom

```
*
 * @form
 * the node form at node/add/[node-type]
 */
function node_entry_form_after_build($form, &$form_state) {


  //set a drupal title here
  drupal_set_title('my title');  


  return $form;
}
```